# Stop audio at determined time and continue when click a button

Tags: html, audio

Hello I want to stop audio at determined time for example I click play and I want to stop it at 5 seconds, when it stops I want to show a button and if you click it the audio will continue again and I need to do it 5 times, any help is welcome

Here is what I have:

```
   <audio controls id="audio2" src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
   </audio>

        <script>
            myAudio=document.getElementById('audio2');
            myAudio.addEventListener('play', function() {
            this.play();
                if(this.currentTime = 5){
                    this.stop();
                }
            });
        </script>

    </audio>
```

Comment: just edit notice: first audio tag should be an open one? are you ok with `</audio>` closing tag

Comment: Already edited it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#audio").on(
        "timeupdate", 
        function(event){
      if (this.currentTime >= 5) {
        $("#audio")[0].pause();
      }
     });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls preload id="audio">
        <source src="cancion.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        Tu navegador no soporta esta caracteristica
    </audio>
    <div id="current">0:00</div>
<div id="duration">0:00</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I did it, finally